# run docker image with csv file

Tags: python, docker

My question is simple, I know  my question is duplicate but I couldn’t solve my problem basic I have a python image which I run with 3 arguments

like `python app.py -s data -f test.csv -b 3`

also, I have a docker image which I created like this

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-bullseye

COPY app /app/app
WORKDIR /app/app
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

I tried to run like this

`docker run --rm -it -v "$PWD":/data/ test_image python3 app.py -f data/test.csv -s data -b 3`
but I am getting error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/test.csv'`

what am I doing wrong

Comment: Your workdir is inside docker is /app/app.. try to create your volume inside /app/app

Comment: Is there are specific reason you need Docker here?  Can you use a non-Docker host-based Python virtual environment instead?  That would be able to directly access the host files without needing any special options.

Comment: yes, I have a reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mounting you're volume to `/data` with `"$PWD":/data/` but you are trying to access `data/` relative to your current location because of the missing leading `/`. Meaning, that you look at `/app/app/data/test.csv` that doesn't exist.

You either can mount your local dir to a different place or adjust your command to something like `app.py -f /data/test.csv`